# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock not working with UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I have an update panel, some input fields, a custom validator and a submit button.
the custom validator has both the client and server validation function.
here is the sample code.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="vldcus" runat="server" OnServerValidate="vldcus_ServerValidate" ClientValidationFunction="vldcus_ClientValidate" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"></asp:CustomValidator>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

the client validation function fire when i click submit button.

here is the code in the client validation function

```
function vldcus_ClientValidate(sender, args) {
            debugger;
            alert("This is client Script");
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
```

and in the server side validation function i register a clientscript block which does not execute i dont know why. here is the server side code.

```
if (TextBox3.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "customScript", "ValidatorValidate(document.getElementById('" + vldcus.ClientID  +"'))", true);
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
```

why the registered script is not executing.

Comment: does that give any error/exception?

Comment: also where is your ValidatorValidate() function

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Server Alert.');", true); add this and check if you get an alert or not ?

Comment: @KrunalPatil There is no error/exception generated and also there is no need for defination of ValidatorValidate() function because this function is available in .net validation api and there is no alert show.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this RegisterClientScriptBlock. As i tried it myself and is showing alert on from the code behind.

```
 protected void vldcus_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (TextBox3.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "customScript", "<script>alert('This is Server Alert');</script>", false);
        }
    }
```

please check the image below 
[image]

Comment: well when i change the code as u suggested its working fine, but when i change the "<script>alert('This is Server Alert');</script>" with my code "ValidatorValidate(document.getElementById('" + vldcus.ClientID  +"'))" its not working... why not the function get execution.